# Giving alternate name to a module in Perl

Tags: perl, module, naming

Is it possible in Perl to assign a new name to a module for use within our code?

My purpose is: some of my clients want .xls files (Spreadsheet::Excel) and others .xlsx (Excel::Writer::XLSX). Since both the modules share most of their API, I'd like to be able to set that option once at the beginning of the project some place and then forget about it, which would also make it easy to change it in the future. It could also perhaps used for things like Mouse/Moose changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that all you really want is to be able to call class methods (like `new`) on a class whose name is determined at runtime.  That's actually quite simple:

```
my $spreadsheet_class = 'Spreadsheet::Excel';
my $sheet = $spreadsheet_class->new;
```

When you call a method on a scalar variable that contains a string, Perl treats it as a class method on the package of that name.  No fancy symbol table hacks required, and it works just fine under `use strict`.

Comment: That is rather true, all I'm doing is calling `new` on the module in different places. I'd assumed `use strict` would complain about this too (like it complains about 'soft ref's), but it doesn't in practice, so this works out. Also gives me easier control over the scoping of this name. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a scenario where this wouldn't suffice and @amon's solution would be made necessary?

Comment: It only lets you call class methods.  If you need to do something like `$Class::config_var = 1;` then you'd need to use @amon's solution (or enable symbolic refs).

Answer (score 6):

You can alias the package stash of a class to a new name:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

package Foo;
sub new { bless [] => shift }
sub hi  { say "hi from Foo" }

package main;

# Alias the package to a new name:
local *F:: = *Foo::;  # it could make sense to drop the "local"

# make an objects
my $f = F->new;

# say hi!
say $f;
$f->hi;
```

Output:

```
Foo=ARRAY(0x9fa877c)
hi from Foo
```

Another solution would be to dynamically subclass the package you want.

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

package Foo;
sub new { bless [] => shift }
sub hi  { say "hi from Foo" }

package Whatever;
# no contents

package main;

# let Whatever inherit from Foo:
# note that I assign, instead of `push` or `unshift` to guarantee single inheritance
@Whatever::ISA = 'Foo'; 

# make an objects
my $w = Whatever->new;

# say hi!
say $w;
$w->hi;
```

Output:

```
Whatever=ARRAY(0x9740758)
hi from Foo
```

Both of these solutions work at runtime and are very flexible. The 2nd solution relies on less magic, and seems cleaner. However, there is a chance that a module tests for `ref($obj) eq 'Foo'` instead of the correct `blessed $obj and $obj->isa('Foo')`, which may cause breakage.

Comment: Great answer, thank! As a side note, I myself was using the `ref($obj) eq 'Classname'` form in a few places, changing them right now. :)

Comment: @sundar `blessed` is of course `Scalar::Util::blessed` (just making sure this is clear). If you compare for `ref`-equality, subclasses won't work. The `blessed` test makes sure that we don't get any *Can't call method "isa" on unblessed reference* errors.

Comment: You just rewrote [`Package::Alias`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Package::Alias)!

Comment: This is serious overkill if you just need to call class methods on a class determined at runtime.

Comment: @cjm Indeed, I was thinking too complicated. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @mob Thanks for the link, I didn't know about that module. (Although, in my hubris, I fail to see why people are so scared by typeglobs that they want to wedge another module in between. P::A only adds a sanity check and auto-`use`).